# Error in setGroupHeaders function: this.p is undefined in line this.p.groupHeader = o;

Tags: jqgrid

I got an error message when trying use goupHeader as stated in the title, so that groupHeader did not work. I have follow all instruction as wiki. Here my code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery().ready(function (){
    jQuery("#t_dosen_gol").jqGrid({
        url:'{URL_XML}',
        datatype: "xml",
        sortable: false,
        colNames:['UNIT KERJA','III/a', 'III/b', 'III/c','III/d','IV/a','IV/b','IV/c','IV/d','IV/e','JUMLAH'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'satkerNama',index:'satkerNama', width:250},
            {name:'3a',index:'3a', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'3b',index:'3b', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'3c',index:'3c', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'3d',index:'3d', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'4a',index:'4a', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'4b',index:'4b', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'4c',index:'4c', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'4d',index:'4d', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'4e',index:'4e', width:50, align:"center", sortable:false, resizable: false},
            {name:'subtotal',index:'subtotal', width:75,align:"center"}                 
        ],
        //rowNum:10,
        width: 700,
        height: 400,
        //rowList:[10,20,30],
        pager: jQuery('#p_dosen_gol'),
        sortname: 'satkerid',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption:"Tenaga Dosen Tetap Menurut Golongan/Ruang dan Unit Kerja"
    }).navGrid('#p_dosen_gol',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false})});

jQuery("#t_dosen_gol").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', { 
    useColSpanStyle: true, 
    groupHeaders:[ 
        {startColumnName: '3a', numberOfColumns: 9, titleText: 'GOLONGAN/RUANG'} 
    ] 
});
```

How can i fix this problem? Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is very easy: you placed the call of `setGroupHeaders` method **out of** `jQuery(document).ready` block. So you try currently to create the grouping headers *before* the grid will be created. So you should must move the last line inside of the `jQuery(document).ready` block. If you would better format your code such errors will be immediately found.